# jqGrid custom formatter

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

For one of the columns in my jqGrid, I'm providing a custom formatter function.  I'm providing some special cases, but if those conditions aren't met, I'd like to resort to using the built-in date formatter utility method.  It doesn't seem that I'm getting the right combination of $.extend() to create the options that method is expecting.

My colModel for this column:

```
{ name:'expires', 
    index:'7',
    width:90,
    align:"right",
    resizable: false,
    formatter: expireFormat,
    formatoptions: {srcformat:"l, F d, Y g:i:s A",newformat:"n/j/Y"}
},
```

And an example of what I'm trying to do

```
function expireFormat(cellValue, opts, rowObject) {
    if (cellValue == null || cellValue == 1451520000) {
        // a specific date that should show as blank
        return '';
    } else {
        // here is where I'd like to just call the $.fmatter.util.DateFormat
        var dt = new Date(cellValue * 1000);
        var op = $.extend({},opts.date);
        if(!isUndefined(opts.colModel.formatoptions)) {
            op = $.extend({},op,opts.colModel.formatoptions);
        }
        return $.fmatter.util.DateFormat(op.srcformat,dt,op.newformat,op);
    }
}
```

(An exception is being thrown in the guts of that DateFormat method, looks like where it's trying to read into a masks property of the options that get passed in)

**EDIT:**

The $.extend that put everything in the place it needed was getting it from that global property where the i18n library set it, **$.jgrid.formatter.date**.

```
var op = $.extend({}, $.jgrid.formatter.date);
if(!isUndefined(opts.colModel.formatoptions)) {
    op = $.extend({}, op, opts.colModel.formatoptions);
}
return $.fmatter.util.DateFormat(op.srcformat,dt.toLocaleString(),op.newformat,op);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the jqGrid source code, different options are passed to the formatter when it is a built-in function versus when a custom formatter is used:

```
    formatter = function (rowId, cellval , colpos, rwdat, _act){
        var cm = ts.p.colModel[colpos],v;
        if(typeof cm.formatter !== 'undefined') {
            var opts= {rowId: rowId, colModel:cm, gid:ts.p.id };
            if($.isFunction( cm.formatter ) ) {
                v = cm.formatter.call(ts,cellval,opts,rwdat,_act);
            } else if($.fmatter){
                v = $.fn.fmatter(cm.formatter, cellval,opts, rwdat, _act);
            } else {
                v = cellVal(cellval);
            }
        } else {
            v = cellVal(cellval);
        }
        return v;
    },
```

So basically what's going on is that when a built-in formatter is used, `cm.formatter` is passed as an argument. I need to confirm this, but based upon the error you are receiving, this appears to be a copy of the `formatter` options from grid.locale-en.js (or whatever version of the i18n file you are using). So when called internally the formatter would contain additional options such as `masks` - which is the one your code is failing on.

As a preventative measure, I would try adding `masks` to your `op` variable. If that solves your problem then great, otherwise keep adding other missing options back into your code until it works.

Does that help?

Comment: Yes, seems I had to extend from the i18n formatter options, found the right combination.  Thanks!